# How do I count the number of wins for each, X and O for my program in java?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

So I've been trying to figure out a way to count each time someone wins in a tic tac toe GUI game I am making. I already made methods to check the tic tac toe board for any winning combinations for either X or O. I am just stumped on how I could count each time the checkWinsX and checkWinsO are called. I tried to make another method that would add a point to either X or O, but I kinda failed at that lol.

```
public class ticTacToeFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int turn = 0; //Deterines the turn
int winsX; //Tracks total wins for X
int winsO; //Tracks total wins for O

public ticTacToeFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

public void clearAll() {
    ulBUT.setText("");
    umBUT.setText("");
    urBUT.setText("");
    mlBUT.setText("");
    centerBUT.setText("");
    mrBUT.setText("");
    llBUT.setText("");
    lmBUT.setText("");
    lrBUT.setText("");
    statusTF.setText("");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I tried to make something of this sort multiple times here to count the checkWins, and so far this is the one that would seem to start off the best in my head
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static int wins() {
    int winsX = 0;
    int winsO = 0;


}

public void checkWinX(int wins) {
    //Top row horizontal check for winning
    if (ulBUT.getText().equals("X") &&  umBUT.getText().equals("X") && urBUT.getText().equals("X")) {
        statusTF.setText("X Wins Horizontally In The Top Row!");
    }
    //Middle row horizontal check for winning
    else if (mlBUT.getText().equals("X") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("X") && mrBUT.getText().equals("X")) {
        statusTF.setText("X Wins Horizontally In The Middle Row!");
    }
    //Bottom row horizontal check for winning
    else if (llBUT.getText().equals("X") &&  lmBUT.getText().equals("X") && lrBUT.getText().equals("X")) {
        statusTF.setText("X Wins Horizontally In The Bottom Row!");
    }
    //Diagonal check for winning
    else if (ulBUT.getText().equals("X") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("X") && lrBUT.getText().equals("X")) {
        statusTF.setText("X Wins Diagonnaly!");
    }
    else if (urBUT.getText().equals("X") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("X") && llBUT.getText().equals("X")) {
        statusTF.setText("X Wins Diagonnaly!");
    }
}

public void checkWinO() {
    //Top row horizontal check for winning
    if (ulBUT.getText().equals("O") &&  umBUT.getText().equals("O") && urBUT.getText().equals("O")) {
        statusTF.setText("O Wins Horizontally In The Top Row!");
    }
    //Middle row horizontal check for winning
    else if (mlBUT.getText().equals("O") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("O") && mrBUT.getText().equals("O")) {
        statusTF.setText("O Wins Horizontally In The Middle Row!");
    }
    //Bottom row horizontal check for winning
    else if (llBUT.getText().equals("O") &&  lmBUT.getText().equals("O") && lrBUT.getText().equals("O")) {
        statusTF.setText("O Wins Horizontally In The Bottom Row!");
    }
    //Diagonal check for winning
    else if (ulBUT.getText().equals("O") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("O") && lrBUT.getText().equals("O")) {
        statusTF.setText("O Wins Diagonnaly!");
    }
    else if (urBUT.getText().equals("O") &&  centerBUT.getText().equals("O") && llBUT.getText().equals("O")) {
        statusTF.setText("O Wins Diagonnaly!");
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    ulPAN = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    ulBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    umBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    urBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    mlBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    centerBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    mrBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    llBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lmBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lrBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    statusTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    oWinsTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    xWinsTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    resetGameBUT = new javax.swing.JButton();
    turnTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    tiesTF1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe | John Gironda");
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(87, 87, 87));

    ulPAN.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 3));

    ulBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ulBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(ulBUT);

    umBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            umBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(umBUT);

    urBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            urBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(urBUT);

    mlBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            mlBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(mlBUT);

    centerBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            centerBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(centerBUT);

    mrBUT.setToolTipText("");
    mrBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            mrBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(mrBUT);

    llBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            llBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(llBUT);

    lmBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lmBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(lmBUT);

    lrBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lrBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    ulPAN.add(lrBUT);

    statusTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            statusTFActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    oWinsTF.setText("Total O Wins: 0");
    oWinsTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            oWinsTFActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    xWinsTF.setText("Total X Wins: 0");
    xWinsTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            xWinsTFActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    resetGameBUT.setText("RESET");
    resetGameBUT.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            resetGameBUTActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    turnTF.setText("Turn: X");
    turnTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            turnTFActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tiesTF1.setText("Total Ties: 0");
    tiesTF1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tiesTF1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(ulPAN, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 400, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(statusTF)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(xWinsTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(turnTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(tiesTF1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(oWinsTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(resetGameBUT, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(ulPAN, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                    .addComponent(resetGameBUT, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(xWinsTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(statusTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(oWinsTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(tiesTF1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                    .addComponent(turnTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void ulBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (ulBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        ulBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            ulBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void umBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (umBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        umBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            umBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void urBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (urBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        urBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            urBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void mlBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (mlBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        mlBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            mlBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void centerBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if (centerBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        centerBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            centerBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                         

private void mrBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (mrBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        mrBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            mrBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void llBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (llBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        llBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            llBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void lmBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (lmBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        lmBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            lmBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void lrBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if (lrBUT.getText().equals("")) {
        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        lrBUT.setText("X");
        } else {
            lrBUT.setText("O");
        }
        turn++;
        checkWinX();
        checkWinO();
    }
}                                     

private void resetGameBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    clearAll(); 
}                                            

private void statusTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void xWinsTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void oWinsTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void turnTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void tiesTF1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ticTacToeFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ticTacToeFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ticTacToeFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ticTacToeFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ticTacToeFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton centerBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton llBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton lmBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton lrBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton mlBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton mrBUT;
private javax.swing.JTextField oWinsTF;
private javax.swing.JButton resetGameBUT;
private javax.swing.JTextField statusTF;
private javax.swing.JTextField tiesTF1;
private javax.swing.JTextField turnTF;
private javax.swing.JButton ulBUT;
private javax.swing.JPanel ulPAN;
private javax.swing.JButton umBUT;
private javax.swing.JButton urBUT;
private javax.swing.JTextField xWinsTF;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have to tell you you are going about this all wrong. Start with a GameModel

```
public class TicTacToeModel {
  Boolean[][] board; //use Boolean class rather than boolean primative so you can set board spaces that haven't been taken yet null
  public void setSpace (int x, int y, boolean isX) throws SpaceTakenException { ... }
  public boolean getSpace(int x, int y) { ... }
  public Boolean calculateWinner() { ... } // calculate if there's a winner, and return its Boolean value if so. Otherwise null
}
```

Once that's done and working, you can adapt a GUI to your model.

Answer (score 0):

In your wins() method, you could pass in a parameter indicating X or O and increment the respective counter variable.

For example:

```
public int win(int player) {
    if(player == 0) {
        winsX++;
    }
    else {
        winsY++;
    }
}
```

And then call this every time you check and find that a player has won.